# how merge with filling table

Tags: python, pandas, merge, fill

I have two tables. I need to replace the col3 field of table one with the col6 value from table 2, provided that the values in col1, col2 match. If they don't match fill in Nan. tables of different sizes

first table

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 |
| 11 | 12 | 13 | 81 |

second table:

| col1 | col2 | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 45 |
| 2 | 4 | 12 |
| 11 | 14 | 13 |

result:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 45 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 | 12 | 8 |
| 11 | 12 | NaN | 81 |

Comment: This is fairly easy. You simply delete `col3` in your table one, then `merge` tabe one and table two. Or there is any other issue with this?

Comment: `df1.assign(col3= df1.merge(df2, on=["col1", "col2"], how="left")["col6"])` ?